# instead of file pointer, we want to write fseek with buffer pointer

Tags: c, pointers, fseek

In an application, I need to replace `fseek`. the file pointer is passed to `fseek` but we need to pass buffer pointer. I want to shift buffer pointer by an offset.

Can anybody suggest me how could I do that or send me sample code.

```
fseek_buff(uint8 * buff, int offset, int SEEK_SET);
```

PS: I need `SEEK_SET` always as whence.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just add or subtract from the pointer?  Keep in mind you'll need the original pointer to free the memory so you might consider a struct or class to hold the current offset along with the original pointer value and any other bookkeeping you find you need.  It would probably help for you to explain why you need this and how you would use it since right now it's just a guess at what you're looking for.

Comment: You sound like you want to generalize or abstract the notion of file to streams and buffers as well.   (seek, tell, read, write, etc).   Maybe check out the GIO library in glib?